# How to sort user names that are in multiple languages by specific languages order in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have user names that are in multiple languages, and I have to sort the names by the **'Korean → English → And other languages in unicode'** order. And additionally, when they are in same languages, I have to sort based on the order they are specified in the unicode as well.

So for example, if first user name is in Korean and second user name is in English, first user comes before second user. And another example, if first user name is English and second user name is also in English, I have to sort this as well.

I made functions that checks if they are in specific languages.

`isKorean` checks for if it's in Korean, `isEnglish` is checks English, and if it's not both, it will be other languages.

```
const isKorean = (str) => {
  const regExp = /^[ㄱ-ㅎ|ㅏ-ㅣ|가-힣]*$/;
  if (regExp.test(str)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

const isEnglish = (str) => {
  const regExp = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
  if (regExp.test(str)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

However these are my problems.

1. I do not know how to sort user names even I know what languages they are in
2. I do not know how to sort user names even when they are in same languages.

So my question is...

1. **How do you sort user names in Korean → English → Other languages order after checking what language they are in?**
2. **And once first one is resolved, how do I sort user names that are in same languages?**

   1. user names in Korean
   2. user names in English
   3. user names in other languages

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not do it by phoenetics, make function that translatesthem into phoenetics. Then sort them by sound

Comment: @StepPen-codes Because that's the requirement

Comment: what do you mean? Also I think you should categorize them by writting system and not the language. I mean there are many languages that uses alphabet not just english

Comment: For english names, I think Array.sort() can handle that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first separate out the list into three lists: Korean, English, Other, then sort each one, and then concatenate them. JS Array Sort doesn't have a built-in way to do multi-faceted sorting (also known as "group by" sorting)

note: I'm not handling when a name matches *both* Korean and English here

```js
const isKorean = (str) => {
  const regExp = /^[ㄱ-ㅎ|ㅏ-ㅣ|가-힣]*$/;
  if (regExp.test(str)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

const isEnglish = (str) => {
  const regExp = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
  if (regExp.test(str)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

const names = ['무현', 'Mark', 'Шумело', 'Brad', '규영', 'Tom', 'Consuela', '차빈', '규영', '차빈', '시훈', 'Ярослав', ];

const korean = names.filter(isKorean).sort();
const english = names.filter(isEnglish).sort();
const other = names.filter((n) => !isKorean(n) && !isEnglish(n)).sort();

const sorted = [...korean, ...english, ...other];
console.log(sorted);
/*
[
  "규영",
  "규영",
  "무현",
  "시훈",
  "차빈",
  "차빈",
  "Brad",
  "Consuela",
  "Mark",
  "Tom",
  "Шумело",
  "Ярослав"
]*/
```

Comment: I couldn't think of making them into each array and concatenating them. This is brilliant. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER TO SECOND QUESTION**
*How to sort the name?*

I don't really know korean but I think Array.sort() can help you.

```
Array.sort()
```

it is a function readily available to Arrays. It works for strings, not just integers and numbers.

```js
const names = {
  hangul: ['무현', '규영', '차빈', '규영', '차빈', '시훈'],
  alphabet: ['James', 'Tanya', 'Borsilli', 'Kazhat', 'Lee']
}

for (let system in names) {
  let print = `${system} unsorted => `
  let printSorted = `sorted => `
  for (let name in names[system])
    print += `${names[system][name]}, `
  for (let name in names[system].sort())
    printSorted += `${names[system][name]}, `

  console.log(print, '\n', printSorted)
}
```

References
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: You're making an assumption here that the `names` are already provided separated by language, which does not seem to be the case based on the question.

Comment: I just provided the answer to the 2nd question, sorting the names, also he already has the filters for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to match a sequence of a-z, A-Z and spaces:

```
/[a-zA-Z ]+/
```

```
const isKorean = (str) => {
  const regExp = /^[ㄱ-ㅎ|ㅏ-ㅣ|가-힣]*$/;
  if (regExp.test(str)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

const isEnglish = (str) => {
  const regExp = /[a-zA-Z ]+/;
  if (regExp.test(str)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

const names = ['김무현', 'Albert Mark','May Carrie', 'LUO LOGN'];

const korean = names.filter(isKorean).sort();
const english = names.filter(isEnglish).sort();
const other = names.filter((n) => !isKorean(n) && !isEnglish(n)).sort();

const sorted = [...korean, ...english, ...other];
console.log(sorted);
```